# Release life cycle and version numbers

Tags: versioning, release-cycle

I'm working on a lot of small utility scripts for users in my office, and I want to develop a release cycle/version number system to use when testing and distributing these tools to users. I'm  not sure what the relationship should be between release cycles stages (alpha, beta, release candidate) and version numbers (1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.1 etc).

Say I release version 0.1.0 of a tool. I call it 0.1.0-beta and give it to some users to test. They don't find any problems, so I don't need to make any changes to the code. Do I then just say that 0.1.0 is no longer a beta release, or do I make a new version number?

Answer (score 1):

According to Semantic Versioning 2.0.0-rc.1 (see that version number there) the short answer is you would simply name the released version 0.1.0 which would be considered greater than 0.1.0-beta.

The full nitty gritty is here: http://semver.org

I cannot comment on personal experience with using this approach but it seems reasonably thought through, and there's a discussion relating to it over on its github issues page: https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues